# how to count decrement ng-click limit zero

Tags: javascript, angularjs

we have done in increment but decrent will minus i have not an minus only for limit zero

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="count = count + 1">+</button>
    <p>
      <input name="vas" ng-model="count" value="{{ count }}"></input>
    </p>
    <div ng-click="count = count - 1 ">-</div>


    {{count*10}}
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.count = 0;


    });

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please post the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to disable `-` button when counter is zero.

```
<button  ng-click="count = count - 1 " ng-disabled="count == 0">-</button>
```